# Is there a way to find out which Python method can raise which Exception or Error

Tags: python, function, exception, methods

Is there a way to find out which Python method can raise which Exception or Error? I didn't find much about it in the official Python documentation.

Comment: Virtually anything can raise an exception, particularly if you pass it arguments it can't handle.

Comment: By "which Python method can raise which Exception or Error" do you mean which method _will_ raise it, or just has the ability to raise it?

Comment: I mean the Excpetions/Errors which possibly can be raised by a specific method.

Comment: Then the answer is "no".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the answer is no.  Some of the exceptions are documented but most just follow a general pattern that can be learned.  *SyntaxError* is checked first and is raised for syntactically invalid code.  *NameError* arises when a variable is undefined (not assigned yet or misspelled).  *TypeError* is raised for the wrong number of arguments or mismatched data types.  *ValueError* means the type is correct and but the value doesn't make sense for the function (i.e. negative inputs to math.sqrt().  If the value is an index in a sequence lookup, *IndexError* is raised.  If the value is a key for a mapping lookup, *KeyError* is raised.  Another common exception is *AttributeError* for missing attributes.  *IOError* is for failed I/O.  And *OSError* for operating system errors.

Besides learning the common patterns, it is usually easy to just run a function and see what exception it raises in a given circumstance.

In general a function cannot know or document all the possible errors, because the inputs can raise their own exceptions.  Consider this function:

```
def f(a, b):
    return a + b
```

It can raise *TypeError* if the number of arguments are wrong or if *a* doesn't support the `__add__` method.  However, the underlying data can raise different exceptions:

```
>>> f(10)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    f(10)
TypeError: f() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
>>> f(10, 20)
30
>>> f('hello', 'world')
'helloworld'
>>> f(10, 'world')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    f(10, 'world')
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 2, in f
    return a + b
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
>>> class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __add__(self, other):
        raise RuntimeError(other)

>>> f(A(5), A(7))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    f(A(5), A(7))
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 2, in f
    return a + b
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 5, in __add__
    raise RuntimeError(other)
RuntimeError: <__main__.A instance at 0x103ce2ab8>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the name of the exception with `__name__` , example :

```
try : 
    some_function()
except Exception as ex : 
    print('function: {0}, exception: {1}'.format(some_function.__name__, type(ex).__name__))
```